# IllegalStateException while using UserTransaction (Java EE)

Tags: java-ee-6, openjpa, illegalstateexception

I am trying to make my first Java Enterprise Application and use `UserTransaction`s.
Therefore I use JNDI Lookup with `java:comp/UserTransaction` to get my UserTransaction Object.

```
public void myMethod(MyEntity e) throws ApplicationException {
    try {
        this.ut = getUserTransaction();
        this.ut.begin();
        this.myStatefulBean.myBusinessMethod(e);
    } catch ...
```

When I start my Transaction with `.begin()` and try to invoke any method in my stateful Bean (which works properly *before* starting a UserTransaction) I get an `EJBTransactionRolledbackException` which leads me to the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot add non-XA Resource to global JTS transaction
```

The Bean I am using is annotated with `@DataSourceDefinition` having `className = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientXADataSource"` thus there is imo no non-XA Resource. 
What am I doing wrong?

I am using openjpa 2.2.1, Java EE Version 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by myself. I used in my DataSourceDefinition `name = "java:global/jdbc/testDB"` as name, but in my `persistence.xml` the DataSource name was defined as `<jta-data-source>testDB</jta-data-source>`

This seems to work in CMTs but not in a UserTransaction. Correcting the entry in persistence.xml to `<jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/testDB</jta-data-source>` fixed the problem.